# Compare dates in multiple columns and extract column name with the oldest date

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data as below with multiple columns having date. I want to compare all date columns and column name of that has the oldest date.
I tried the code as below but it doest work

```
library(tidyverse)

min_dates <- mydata %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(min_date = min(as.Date(c_across(c_returned:received_date), na.rm = TRUE)))

# Find the name of the column with the minimum date for each row
min_dates <- mydata %>%
  mutate(column_name = colnames(data)[apply(data, 1, function(row) which.min(row))])
```

**data**

```
mydata <- structure(list(record_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), occur = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "track"), class = "factor"), 
    event = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L), c_returned = structure(c(NA, 
    58L, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("1/10/21", "1/10/22", "1/11/21", 
    "1/11/22", "1/12/23", "1/13/22", "1/14/23", "1/15/23", "1/19/23", 
    "1/21/22", "1/25/23", "1/26/23", "1/4/22", "1/6/21", "1/6/23", 
    "1/7/21", "1/8/21", "1/9/21", "10/11/21", "10/11/22", "10/15/20", 
    "10/16/20", "10/16/21", "10/17/20", "10/18/20", "10/18/21", 
    "10/19/20", "10/19/21", "10/19/22", "10/2/22", "10/20/20", 
    "10/21/20", "10/22/20", "10/29/21", "10/30/21", "10/31/22", 
    "10/7/21", "10/8/21", "11/10/20", "11/11/22", "11/15/19", 
    "11/16/19", "11/16/21", "11/17/19", "11/17/21", "11/17/22", 
    "11/18/19", "11/19/19", "11/20/19", "11/21/19", "11/22/19", 
    "11/23/19", "11/24/19", "11/25/19", "11/26/19", "11/27/19", 
    "11/5/20", "11/7/19", "11/8/19", "12/10/21", "12/11/21", 
    "12/13/19", "12/14/19", "12/16/22", "12/17/22", "12/20/22", 
    "12/22/22", "12/23/21", "12/23/22", "12/26/21", "12/27/22", 
    "12/28/20", "12/31/22", "12/5/22", "12/7/20", "12/8/21", 
    "2/12/20", "2/13/20", "2/14/20", "2/15/20", "2/15/21", "2/15/22", 
    "2/16/21", "2/17/21", "2/18/20", "2/19/20", "2/2/22", "2/20/20", 
    "2/23/22", "2/24/23", "3/10/21", "3/11/21", "3/12/21", "3/12/23", 
    "3/13/23", "3/14/23", "3/15/23", "3/16/23", "3/17/20", "3/18/22", 
    "3/2/22", "3/22/22", "3/22/23", "3/23/22", "3/23/23", "3/3/22", 
    "3/6/23", "3/7/23", "3/8/23", "3/9/21", "3/9/22", "4/1/23", 
    "4/10/23", "4/12/23", "4/2/23", "4/21/23", "4/22/22", "4/22/23", 
    "4/23/20", "4/23/23", "4/24/23", "4/25/23", "4/26/21", "4/26/23", 
    "4/27/21", "4/3/23", "4/4/23", "4/9/23", "5/1/20", "5/12/21", 
    "5/12/22", "5/13/23", "5/14/23", "5/15/23", "5/16/23", "5/17/23", 
    "5/19/23", "5/31/23", "5/9/22", "6/1/22", "6/14/23", "6/15/23", 
    "6/16/22", "6/16/23", "6/17/23", "6/18/22", "6/18/23", "6/20/22", 
    "6/23/22", "6/26/23", "6/27/23", "6/28/22", "6/29/22", "7/1/23", 
    "7/21/22", "7/7/22", "8/18/21", "8/19/21", "8/20/21", "8/24/22", 
    "8/3/20", "9/11/22", "9/13/22", "9/14/22", "9/24/21", "9/26/22", 
    "9/27/21", "9/27/22"), class = "factor"), sign_date = structure(c(56L, 
    NA, 85L, NA, 312L, NA), .Label = c("1/1/00", "1/11/23", "1/12/23", 
    "1/13/23", "1/14/20", "1/15/19", "1/15/20", "1/16/20", "1/17/20", 
    "1/17/23", "1/19/22", "1/20/21", "1/20/22", "1/20/23", "1/21/21", 
    "1/22/20", "1/24/20", "1/26/22", "1/28/21", "1/3/20", "1/30/20", 
    "1/6/20", "1/6/21", "1/7/21", "1/7/22", "1/8/20", "1/9/19", 
    "1/9/20", "10/1/18", "10/11/19", "10/11/22", "10/12/22", 
    "10/14/19", "10/14/20", "10/15/18", "10/15/19", "10/15/21", 
    "10/16/18", "10/17/22", "10/18/19", "10/18/22", "10/19/22", 
    "10/2/18", "10/21/19", "10/21/20", "10/21/22", "10/22/18", 
    "10/22/20", "10/22/21", "10/23/19", "10/25/19", "10/26/22", 
    "10/27/21", "10/28/19", "10/28/22", "10/29/18", "10/29/19", 
    "10/3/19", "10/3/22", "10/31/19", "10/5/18", "10/5/22", "10/8/18", 
    "10/8/19", "10/9/18", "10/9/19", "11/1/18", "11/10/21", "11/12/18", 
    "11/12/19", "11/12/20", "11/13/19", "11/15/21", "11/18/21", 
    "11/18/22", "11/2/20", "11/2/22", "11/20/19", "11/20/20", 
    "11/21/22", "11/22/19", "11/23/20", "11/23/21", "11/26/19", 
    "11/27/18", "11/27/19", "11/28/22", "11/3/21", "11/3/22", 
    "11/4/19", "11/4/20", "11/5/20", "11/7/19", "11/7/22", "11/8/22", 
    "12/11/18", "12/12/19", "12/13/19", "12/14/21", "12/15/22", 
    "12/16/22", "12/17/18", "12/17/19", "12/17/20", "12/18/19", 
    "12/19/22", "12/2/19", "12/2/20", "12/2/22", "12/22/20", 
    "12/23/19", "12/24/19", "12/4/20", "12/6/18", "12/7/18", 
    "12/7/22", "12/8/22", "2/1/19", "2/11/19", "2/12/21", "2/13/23", 
    "2/15/22", "2/16/23", "2/17/21", "2/19/19", "2/19/20", "2/20/19", 
    "2/20/20", "2/21/19", "2/21/20", "2/22/19", "2/22/22", "2/23/21", 
    "2/24/20", "2/24/23", "2/26/20", "2/26/21", "2/28/20", "2/4/21", 
    "2/5/19", "2/5/20", "2/6/22", "2/6/23", "2/8/19", "2/8/20", 
    "2/9/22", "2/9/23", "3/11/20", "3/12/21", "3/13/19", "3/13/20", 
    "3/13/23", "3/14/23", "3/16/20", "3/17/21", "3/19/20", "3/2/21", 
    "3/21/22", "3/23/22", "3/24/21", "3/24/23", "3/28/19", "3/29/19", 
    "3/29/21", "3/4/20", "3/4/21", "3/5/20", "3/5/22", "3/6/20", 
    "3/7/19", "3/8/23", "3/9/21", "3/9/22", "4/1/22", "4/10/22", 
    "4/12/21", "4/14/21", "4/16/20", "4/17/20", "4/18/19", "4/19/22", 
    "4/2/20", "4/20/20", "4/20/21", "4/21/21", "4/22/21", "4/22/22", 
    "4/23/21", "4/24/20", "4/25/22", "4/26/23", "4/27/22", "4/27/23", 
    "4/28/20", "4/28/21", "4/28/23", "4/30/19", "4/4/22", "4/5/22", 
    "4/6/23", "4/7/07", "4/7/21", "5/1/19", "5/10/22", "5/11/22", 
    "5/12/20", "5/12/22", "5/13/19", "5/13/22", "5/15/19", "5/16/19", 
    "5/16/22", "5/19/21", "5/2/22", "5/20/20", "5/21/20", "5/22/20", 
    "5/24/19", "5/24/22", "5/25/22", "5/26/20", "5/28/19", "5/29/20", 
    "5/3/19", "5/30/20", "5/4/22", "5/5/21", "5/5/23", "5/6/22", 
    "6/1/20", "6/10/19", "6/10/21", "6/11/21", "6/13/19", "6/14/22", 
    "6/15/21", "6/16/20", "6/17/19", "6/17/21", "6/19/19", "6/2/22", 
    "6/20/19", "6/22/20", "6/22/22", "6/23/21", "6/24/22", "6/26/19", 
    "6/27/22", "6/29/21", "6/29/22", "6/3/20", "6/30/21", "6/30/22", 
    "6/5/19", "6/5/20", "6/6/22", "6/7/19", "6/8/20", "6/8/22", 
    "6/9/20", "6/9/22", "7/1/19", "7/1/21", "7/10/20", "7/11/19", 
    "7/12/19", "7/12/22", "7/13/20", "7/14/22", "7/15/19", "7/16/21", 
    "7/19/19", "7/19/21", "7/2/19", "7/20/22", "7/21/20", "7/22/21", 
    "7/24/19", "7/24/20", "7/26/19", "7/27/22", "7/29/19", "7/29/22", 
    "7/30/20", "7/31/19", "7/6/22", "7/7/22", "7/9/19", "8/1/19", 
    "8/10/21", "8/11/20", "8/12/21", "8/12/22", "8/13/19", "8/16/19", 
    "8/17/20", "8/19/20", "8/2/19", "8/20/19", "8/21/19", "8/22/19", 
    "8/22/22", "8/23/19", "8/24/19", "8/25/19", "8/26/19", "8/26/21", 
    "8/27/21", "8/28/19", "8/29/22", "8/3/19", "8/30/18", "8/30/19", 
    "8/31/20", "8/4/22", "8/6/21", "8/7/19", "8/7/20", "8/8/19", 
    "8/9/19", "9/10/20", "9/11/18", "9/11/19", "9/11/20", "9/13/18", 
    "9/13/19", "9/13/21", "9/14/20", "9/14/22", "9/15/20", "9/16/19", 
    "9/17/18", "9/17/19", "9/18/18", "9/19/19", "9/2/20", "9/2/21", 
    "9/20/19", "9/25/19", "9/26/19", "9/27/19", "9/28/18", "9/28/21", 
    "9/3/19", "9/3/20", "9/3/21", "9/30/19", "9/30/21", "9/4/19", 
    "9/5/19", "9/6/19", "9/7/21", "9/8/22", "9/9/19", "9/9/20", 
    "9/9/22"), class = "factor"), re_returned_date = structure(c(44L, 
    NA, 80L, NA, 83L, NA), .Label = c("1/10/21", "1/10/23", "1/14/23", 
    "1/23/19", "1/23/22", "1/23/23", "1/24/21", "1/28/20", "1/29/20", 
    "1/29/21", "1/3/23", "1/30/21", "1/30/23", "1/31/20", "1/6/21", 
    "1/7/21", "1/7/23", "1/8/19", "1/8/21", "10/10/18", "10/12/20", 
    "10/13/20", "10/14/19", "10/15/18", "10/16/19", "10/18/19", 
    "10/19/19", "10/19/20", "10/19/21", "10/20/18", "10/21/18", 
    "10/21/19", "10/22/19", "10/23/20", "10/24/20", "10/26/19", 
    "10/27/18", "10/28/21", "10/29/19", "10/4/19", "10/6/19", 
    "10/6/22", "11/1/21", "11/10/18", "11/10/21", "11/12/19", 
    "11/12/22", "11/13/19", "11/13/20", "11/14/22", "11/15/19", 
    "11/16/19", "11/17/20", "11/17/21", "11/19/21", "11/2/21", 
    "11/20/18", "11/21/19", "11/21/20", "11/24/19", "11/24/22", 
    "11/25/22", "11/26/19", "11/26/21", "11/27/19", "11/29/21", 
    "11/3/19", "11/30/20", "11/4/19", "11/5/18", "11/5/19", "11/5/22", 
    "11/8/19", "11/9/18", "11/9/19", "12/10/20", "12/11/18", 
    "12/11/20", "12/11/22", "12/12/18", "12/13/19", "12/16/20", 
    "12/18/18", "12/18/22", "12/20/19", "12/21/19", "12/22/19", 
    "12/23/19", "12/23/20", "12/28/18", "12/3/19", "12/3/22", 
    "12/30/22", "12/31/22", "12/4/20", "12/4/21", "12/5/20", 
    "12/9/19", "12/9/22", "2/13/20", "2/16/19", "2/16/23", "2/18/19", 
    "2/18/21", "2/23/19", "2/23/22", "2/26/20", "2/26/21", "2/27/21", 
    "2/27/23", "2/28/20", "2/28/23", "2/3/20", "2/4/20", "2/5/20", 
    "2/5/21", "2/5/23", "2/6/23", "2/8/20", "3/10/21", "3/10/22", 
    "3/11/20", "3/12/20", "3/12/23", "3/14/19", "3/14/23", "3/15/23", 
    "3/16/21", "3/16/23", "3/19/19", "3/21/23", "3/22/20", "3/25/20", 
    "3/26/19", "3/27/19", "3/28/21", "3/28/22", "3/3/20", "3/3/22", 
    "3/30/20", "3/31/22", "3/4/19", "3/7/21", "3/8/20", "4/13/23", 
    "4/14/20", "4/15/19", "4/16/21", "4/21/23", "4/22/23", "4/23/19", 
    "4/23/20", "4/27/20", "4/29/20", "4/29/22", "4/30/23", "4/6/21", 
    "4/8/22", "5/1/20", "5/1/22", "5/15/19", "5/15/22", "5/17/22", 
    "5/20/22", "5/21/21", "5/21/22", "5/22/21", "5/23/21", "5/26/20", 
    "5/27/22", "5/28/21", "5/28/22", "5/3/21", "5/3/22", "5/30/20", 
    "5/6/21", "5/7/20", "5/8/22", "5/9/22", "6/10/22", "6/11/19", 
    "6/12/22", "6/13/22", "6/14/20", "6/17/22", "6/18/20", "6/18/22", 
    "6/19/21", "6/2/20", "6/20/22", "6/28/20", "6/29/19", "6/3/22", 
    "6/30/19", "6/4/21", "6/8/19", "6/8/21", "6/9/20", "7/1/19", 
    "7/11/20", "7/12/22", "7/14/21", "7/15/22", "7/17/19", "7/18/20", 
    "7/18/21", "7/18/22", "7/19/20", "7/2/22", "7/20/20", "7/20/21", 
    "7/21/19", "7/22/22", "7/24/22", "7/25/20", "7/27/20", "7/27/21", 
    "7/28/20", "7/28/22", "7/3/21", "7/4/20", "7/4/22", "8/1/19", 
    "8/10/19", "8/13/19", "8/13/20", "8/15/21", "8/15/22", "8/16/21", 
    "8/17/19", "8/2/20", "8/22/21", "8/28/20", "8/29/21", "8/30/20", 
    "8/30/21", "8/5/20", "8/5/21", "8/5/22", "8/6/19", "8/7/21", 
    "8/8/19", "8/8/22", "8/9/19", "8/9/20", "8/9/21", "8/9/22", 
    "9/14/21", "9/15/19", "9/16/22", "9/17/21", "9/19/20", "9/21/19", 
    "9/21/20", "9/22/19", "9/25/19", "9/25/21", "9/26/18", "9/26/19", 
    "9/27/19", "9/27/21", "9/27/22", "9/28/21", "9/28/22", "9/3/22", 
    "9/30/18", "9/4/22", "9/5/21", "9/6/19", "9/7/22", "9/8/21"
    ), class = "factor"), rw_returned_date = structure(c(39L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("1/12/23", "1/23/23", "1/24/22", 
    "1/29/21", "10/1/22", "10/11/22", "10/13/21", "10/15/20", 
    "10/16/20", "10/16/21", "10/18/21", "10/2/22", "10/22/22", 
    "10/23/20", "10/27/22", "10/9/22", "11/12/21", "11/13/21", 
    "11/22/22", "12/30/21", "12/8/22", "2/13/23", "2/2/22", "2/24/23", 
    "2/26/23", "3/14/23", "3/16/22", "3/18/22", "3/21/23", "3/25/22", 
    "3/7/23", "3/9/22", "4/15/22", "4/24/22", "5/10/21", "5/10/22", 
    "5/13/23", "5/19/23", "5/21/21", "5/22/21", "5/23/22", "5/26/21", 
    "5/27/22", "5/31/22", "5/31/23", "5/8/21", "5/9/21", "6/22/21", 
    "6/24/21", "7/1/22", "7/1/23", "7/14/21", "7/19/22", "7/22/22", 
    "7/23/22", "7/25/22", "7/26/22", "8/11/21", "8/9/22", "9/10/22", 
    "9/24/22", "9/25/22"), class = "factor"), ordered_date = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 4L, NA, 136L), .Label = c("1/11/21", "1/12/21", "1/13/21", 
    "1/14/21", "1/15/20", "1/18/21", "1/24/20", "1/24/22", "1/27/20", 
    "1/27/21", "1/29/20", "1/30/20", "1/4/23", "1/5/23", "1/7/20", 
    "1/8/20", "1/9/21", "10/1/19", "10/10/19", "10/13/20", "10/14/20", 
    "10/16/20", "10/18/20", "10/19/20", "10/2/19", "10/2/20", 
    "10/2/21", "10/20/20", "10/21/19", "10/21/20", "10/23/20", 
    "10/26/20", "10/28/19", "10/29/20", "10/4/19", "10/6/20", 
    "10/7/20", "10/8/21", "11/1/20", "11/10/20", "11/12/19", 
    "11/13/19", "11/15/19", "11/16/20", "11/18/21", "11/19/19", 
    "11/21/19", "11/22/19", "11/23/20", "11/23/22", "11/26/19", 
    "11/27/19", "11/30/20", "11/5/19", "11/6/19", "11/6/20", 
    "11/7/19", "11/7/20", "11/9/20", "12/1/19", "12/1/20", "12/13/19", 
    "12/14/20", "12/14/22", "12/16/20", "12/17/19", "12/17/22", 
    "12/18/19", "12/18/21", "12/2/20", "12/20/19", "12/28/22", 
    "12/30/19", "12/8/20", "2/1/21", "2/12/20", "2/17/22", "2/18/20", 
    "2/18/23", "2/21/19", "2/21/20", "2/22/21", "2/24/23", "2/25/22", 
    "2/25/23", "2/26/20", "2/27/20", "2/28/20", "2/3/20", "2/5/20", 
    "2/8/21", "3/14/23", "3/15/23", "3/16/20", "3/16/23", "3/2/20", 
    "3/2/21", "3/20/23", "3/21/22", "3/21/23", "3/22/21", "3/23/21", 
    "3/27/23", "3/28/22", "3/3/23", "3/4/23", "3/6/22", "3/6/23", 
    "3/8/21", "3/8/23", "3/9/21", "3/9/22", "4/1/20", "4/10/20", 
    "4/10/23", "4/11/23", "4/13/21", "4/14/21", "4/15/20", "4/15/21", 
    "4/18/19", "4/19/19", "4/19/21", "4/19/23", "4/21/20", "4/22/21", 
    "4/22/22", "4/23/21", "4/23/22", "4/24/23", "4/25/19", "4/27/21", 
    "4/28/23", "4/29/21", "4/29/23", "4/4/19", "4/4/23", "4/5/20", 
    "4/7/23", "4/8/23", "4/9/19", "5//2019", "5/1/19", "5/13/20", 
    "5/13/21", "5/14/20", "5/15/20", "5/15/23", "5/16/22", "5/16/23", 
    "5/17/21", "5/19/21", "5/20/22", "5/20/23", "5/21/21", "5/24/21", 
    "5/3/23", "5/31/20", "5/4/21", "5/4/23", "5/6/21", "5/8/23", 
    "6/10/21", "6/14/21", "6/15/21", "6/16/20", "6/16/22", "6/18/21", 
    "6/21/22", "6/22/22", "6/23/21", "6/25/20", "6/26/020", "6/26/19", 
    "6/26/20", "6/27/23", "6/29/20", "6/29/22", "6/29/23", "6/4/21", 
    "6/6/22", "6/7/21", "6/9/20", "7/1/20", "7/1/22", "7/10/20", 
    "7/102020", "7/11/22", "7/13/19", "7/13/20", "7/13/21", "7/14/21", 
    "7/15/21", "7/16/21", "7/17/22", "7/20/20", "7/20/21", "7/22/20", 
    "7/25/22", "7/27/21", "7/27/22", "7/29/20", "7/29/21", "7/29/23", 
    "7/30/21", "8/11/20", "8/11/21", "8/12/20", "8/13/21", "8/14/20", 
    "8/16/22", "8/17/21", "8/2/22", "8/21/20", "8/26/22", "8/29/22", 
    "8/31/20", "8/4/21", "8/5/20", "8/5/22", "9/13/22", "9/18/20", 
    "9/2/20", "9/21/20", "9/25/20", "9/29/20", "9/30/19", "9/4/20", 
    "9/7/21"), class = "factor"), received_date = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 87L, NA, 158L), .Label = c("1/11/21", "1/12/21", 
    "1/13/21", "1/14/20", "1/17/22", "1/18/21", "1/18/22", "1/19/21", 
    "1/20/20", "1/21/20", "1/21/21", "1/21/22", "1/23/23", "1/27/20", 
    "1/28/20", "1/4/23", "1/5/20", "1/5/22", "1/6/20", "1/7/20", 
    "1/7/21", "10/12/21", "10/15/21", "10/15/22", "10/17/22", 
    "10/18/22", "10/19/19", "10/19/21", "10/20/21", "10/20/22", 
    "10/21/19", "10/21/22", "10/23/20", "10/25/21", "10/27/20", 
    "10/28/20", "10/29/20", "10/30/19", "10/30/20", "10/4/21", 
    "10/5/21", "10/6/21", "10/8/21", "10/9/19", "1026/2020", 
    "11/1/21", "11/10/19", "11/10/20", "11/15/19", "11/16/20", 
    "11/18/20", "11/2/22", "11/20/20", "11/23/20", "11/24/20", 
    "11/25/20", "11/26/19", "11/26/21", "11/27/20", "11/29/19", 
    "11/3/20", "11/4/20", "11/9/20", "12/11/20", "12/13/19", 
    "12/15/20", "12/17/19", "12/17/20", "12/18/19", "12/2/20", 
    "12/22/20", "12/24/19", "12/29/20", "12/3/20", "12/30/21", 
    "12/30/22", "12/31/19", "12/6/19", "12/7/22", "12/8/20", 
    "12/9/19", "2/0/2021", "2/1/22", "2/12/21", "2/14/20", "2/17/20", 
    "2/17/21", "2/19/20", "2/19/21", "2/2/21", "2/23/21", "2/24/20", 
    "2/24/22", "2/25/20", "2/26/21", "2/27/23", "2/6/20", "2/8/21", 
    "23-06-2023", "3/11/20", "3/13/23", "3/17/20", "3/17/22", 
    "3/18/20", "3/2/23", "3/20/20", "3/23/23", "3/24/20", "3/24/23", 
    "3/26/20", "3/28/23", "3/30/20", "3/30/23", "3/31/23", "3/4/20", 
    "3/4/22", "3/5/20", "3/7/23", "3/9/21", "3/9/23", "4/10/23", 
    "4/12/21", "4/12/23", "4/13/21", "4/14/23", "4/15/23", "4/18/23", 
    "4/21/20", "4/21/23", "4/22/20", "4/22/21", "4/25/19", "4/26/21", 
    "4/27/20", "4/28/21", "4/28/23", "4/29/20", "4/29/23", "4/3/20", 
    "4/3/23", "4/4/23", "4/5/22", "4/5/23", "4/6/23", "4/7/21", 
    "4/7/23", "4/8/21", "4/8/23", "4/9/20", "5/1/20", "5/10/21", 
    "5/10/23", "5/11/23", "5/12/21", "5/13/21", "5/13/23", "5/15/19", 
    "5/16/19", "5/16/23", "5/18/21", "5/20/21", "5/22/23", "5/23/23", 
    "5/25/23", "5/26/21", "5/26/23", "5/28/20", "5/282021", "5/30/19", 
    "5/31/21", "5/4/22", "5/4/23", "5/5/21", "5/6/21", "5/8/20", 
    "5/8/23", "6/1/21", "6/11/19", "6/11/20", "6/11/21", "6/14/21", 
    "6/16/20", "6/16/21", "6/17/20", "6/17/21", "6/18/20", "6/2/21", 
    "6/20/19", "6/21/21", "6/22/20", "6/24/21", "6/25/21", "6/28/22", 
    "6/29/21", "6/3/20", "6/30/20", "6/30/21", "6/5/23", "6/7/23", 
    "6/9/20", "7/1/21", "7/10/19", "7/10/23", "7/12/23", "7/13/20", 
    "7/13/22", "7/15/20", "7/15/22", "7/17/20", "7/18/22", "7/19/21", 
    "7/22/21", "7/22/22", "7/23/20", "7/31/20", "7/7/20", "7/7/22", 
    "7/9/20", "730/2021", "78/2/2021", "8/1/22", "8/10/22", "8/10/23", 
    "8/11/20", "8/11/21", "8/11/22", "8/13/19", "8/13/21", "8/14/20", 
    "8/15/22", "8/17/20", "8/17/21", "8/19/21", "8/19/22", "8/2/21", 
    "8/2/22", "8/23/21", "8/24/21", "8/25/20", "8/25/21", "8/25/22", 
    "8/27/21", "8/27/22", "8/3/20", "8/3/21", "8/31/21", "8/31/22", 
    "8/4/20", "8/4/22", "8/5/20", "8/6/21", "8/8/22", "8/9/19", 
    "9/15/21", "9/18/20", "9/22/21", "9/24/20", "9/27/21", "9/28/21", 
    "9/29/20", "9/30/21", "9/30/22", "9/8/21"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

The major problem with the OP's attempt was that the date columns can not be converted with `as.Date(select(mydata, c_returned:received_date))` on the fly, because `as.Date` can only work with character objects, whereas the code is feeding it a data.frame.
Please check the output of the following code:

```
as.Date(select(mydata, c_returned:received_date))
Error in as.Date.default(select(mydata, c_returned:received_date)) : 
  do not know how to convert 'select(mydata, c_returned:received_date)' to class “Date”
```

We have to convert date columns to proper date class before addressing the question. After that, we can use `rowwise() |> min()` as intended.
The following code introduces two new columns to the dataframe. A column with the lowest value, and a column with the name of the column corresponding to the lowest value.

```
library(dplyr)
mydata |>
    mutate(across(c_returned:received_date, # convert columns to date
                  \(x) lubridate::mdy(as.character(x)))) |>
    rowwise() |>                            # creation of new columns
    mutate(min_date = min(c_across(c_returned:received_date),
                           na.rm = TRUE),   # min date value
           min_date_colname =               # min date col name
               names(pick(c_returned:received_date))[which.min(pick(c_returned:received_date))]) |> 
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 × 11
  record_id occur   event c_returned sign_date  re_returned_date rw_returned_date ordered_date received_date min_date   min_date_colname
      <int> <fct>   <int> <date>     <date>     <date>           <date>           <date>       <date>        <date>     <chr>           
1         1 ""         NA NA         2018-10-29 2018-11-10       2021-05-21       NA           NA            2018-10-29 sign_date       
2         2 ""         NA 2019-11-07 NA         NA               NA               NA           NA            2019-11-07 c_returned      
3         3 ""         NA NA         2018-11-27 2018-12-12       NA               NA           NA            2018-11-27 sign_date       
4         3 "track"     1 NA         NA         NA               NA               2021-01-14   2021-02-17    2021-01-14 ordered_date    
5         4 ""         NA NA         2018-08-30 2018-12-18       NA               NA           NA            2018-08-30 sign_date       
6         4 "track"     1 NA         NA         NA               NA               2019-04-04   2019-05-16    2019-04-04 ordered_date
```

Comment: Error: unexpected input in:
"mydata %>%
  mutate(across(c_returned:received_date,\"

Comment: works fine on my machine. Maybe you have an old version of dplyr? `pick` is relatively new (introduced in early 2023). Try to substitute `across` for `pick`, and see what happens

Comment: please also check whether you have lubridate and dplyr installed, and what versions

Comment: Please also make sure the data provided with `dput` is consistent with the local data you are trying hte answer on

Comment: I think you may have an old version of R. `\(x) x` is also new. Replacing this part with `function(x) x` may help.

Answer (score 0):

A one liner, using pmap (parallel map) from purrr, and mdy from lubridate:

```
mydata |> mutate(min = pmap_vec(across(c_returned:received_date), ~ min(mdy(...), na.rm = TRUE)))
```